# How does locking works in Redis?

Tags: redis

Say Two users are updating/putting the key in same hash , how read/write locks are acquired here ?

```
    hmset user:A:address  city NY     // First user
    hmset user:A:address  city SEATLE // Second user
```

For Example in above case :-
First user will acquire the lock on complete hashmap `user:A:address` and Second user  will be blocked till first user is done ?

What if users are working on separate keys under same hashmap

```
    hmset user:A:address  county test_county  // First user
    hmset user:A:address  zip    01001        // Second user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis processes these commands in a single thread, and doesn't need any lock.

It doesn't matter whether the two users are setting the same field of the hash or different fields of the hash, these commands are processed one-by-one. When Redis is processing a command, it blocks other commands, since Redis is **(mostly)** single-threaded.

Comment: %s/since Redis is single-threaded/since Redis is (mostly) single-threaded/g ;)

Comment: Thanks @ItamarHaber. B.T.W, Vim is the best editor :)

Comment: Normally, Redis has very good performance. In fact, it's too fast, and usually, the bottleneck is I/O, NOT CPU. For most Redis commands, e.g. `SET`, `GET`, `HSET`, you don't need to worry about the performance. However, those slow commands, e.g. `KEYS`, `SORT`, might block Redis for a long time. And you should NOT use them on production environment or you need to run these commands on a dedicated Redis instance.

Comment: Thanks @for_stack. I believe Redis process is always hosted on it own redis server. Right ? Can redis run on existing webserver like tomcat etc ?

Comment: @emilly Redis is running as an independent process. Of course, you can run it on an existing webserver.

Comment: @for_stack Can you give me direction how can i run redis process on existing webserver ?

Comment: @user3198603 Just install Redis on the same machine of your webserver, and start it. Or I misunderstand your question?

Comment: say I installed redis on node_A. On same node I have tomcat. Now I start the tomcat on 8080, do you mean redis process will start automatically ?

Comment: @user3198603 No. You have to start Redis on another port, e.g. 6379, BY YOURSELF.

Comment: Ok Then Redis will always be running as separate process than web server. They can be on same node